Detailed balance in the framework of a stochastic differential equation
The primary feature of thermodynamics at equilibrium is detailed balance.
Suppose the state variable is $X_t \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying a stochastic differential equation
$$
d X_t = b(X_t) d t + \sigma(X_t) d W_t.
$$
Here $W$ is a standard Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^p$, $b: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $\sigma: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ with appropriate conditions.
How do we check that detailed balance is satisfied on $b$ and $\sigma$?

I think you should look for a possible stationary state of the related Fokker-Planck equation (if it exists), e.g. https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01379601. Possibly useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153715/226902

Dear Quillo thank you. Yes I agree an equilibrium measure is a stationary measure. But it is possible to have a steady state that is not an equilibrium measure. I will look at this paper. I am especially interested in characterizing equilibrium measures based on $b$ and $\sigma$, if possible.

You are right, I simplified a lot in my previous comment. Risken's paper, if I remember well, is quite technical but should discuss everything (just for the other users, in case the link breaks in the future: "Solutions of the Fokker-Planck Equation
in Detailed Balance", H. Risken, 1972).

It's not so trivial using only the Langevin equation. A necessary condition for detailed balance is that the stochastic entropy production of the process is 0, this can be defined through stochastic thermodynamics or through an Onsager-Machlup Formalism. However, there is exists processes with 0 entropy production that are not equilibrium ones. However, you can check that 1. the FDT is respected (which is a condition on the noise) 2. The drift term is irrotational (can be writen as a gradient) 3. The dynamics is somewhat bounded (take a force F = cst, the steady state is an equilibrium one...

with U = cst*z only if the dynamics is bounded). To my knowledge, these conditions are sufficient  to say that the system is at equilibrium (from a Fokker-Plank equation perspective as you need to define a stationnary state, which is where FP equations shine) and thus for the dynamics to respect detailed balance.
